# Option buttons validation into a Frame

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, userform

I have two optionbuttons into Frame1.

On OK button to transfer collected data into excel sheet1, I wrote the following code that actually retrieves the Msg but it does not allow to complete the data transference from Userform objets to sheet1

```
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim fr1 As Boolean

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.OptionButton Then
        Select Case ctrl.Parent.Name
        Case "Frame1"
            If ctrl.Value = True Then fr1 = True
        End Select
    End If
Next ctrl

If fr1 = False Then MsgBox "No selection for option buttons in Frame1"

Exit Sub
```

How can I validate optionbuttons into the frame1 without disrupting sending the data to sheet1?

Comment: What’s the validation purpose then?

Comment: Data should be delivered once one option button is activated, with the referred code, the action for the OK button is disrupted, code for the OK button to transfer the data ; 'Make Sheet 1 active
Sheet1.Activate 'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1                             
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = "Accepted"
Else
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = "Rejected"
End If

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your userform and look for the '<<< Customize >>> section

Also, check comments inside code.

```
Option Explicit

Function ValidateOptions() As Boolean

    ' Declare objects
    Dim ctrl As Control

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim oneOptionSelected As Boolean

    ' Loop through each of the forms' controls
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        ' If the control is an option button
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.OptionButton Then
            ' If it's parent is an specific frame
            If ctrl.Parent.Name = "Frame1" Then

                oneOptionSelected = ctrl.Value
                ' If any of the option buttons is selected
                If oneOptionSelected = True Then Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    ' If at least one of the option buttons was checked
    If oneOptionSelected = True Then
        ValidateOptions = True
    Else
        MsgBox "No selection for option buttons in Frame1"
    End If

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim targetSheetName As String
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim cancel As Boolean

    ' <<< Customize this >>>
    targetSheetName = "Sheet1"

    ' Validate options
    If ValidateOptions = False Then Exit Sub

    ' Initialize objects
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetSheetName)

    ' Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A:A")) + 1 ' This code is not reliable. Look for solutions on how to find next empty row here in SO

    If Me.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        targetSheet.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = "Accepted"
    Else
        targetSheet.Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = "Rejected"
    End If

End Sub
```